# Query with LEFT JOIN in a specific order

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `Products` with:

```
ProductID
Name
```

And a table called `Product_Images` with:

```
ImageID
ProductID
Filename
Image_Type
Image_Order
```

The `Image_Type` can be one of two options (A or B) and the order allows multiple images of each type to be shown in a specific order.

The query I was using was like:

```
SELECT ProductID,
       Name, 
       IFNULL((SELECT Filename 
                 FROM Product_Images 
                WHERE ProductID = Products.ProductID 
             ORDER BY Image_Type DESC, 
                      Image_Order 
                LIMIT 1),
             'no_image.jpg') AS Image_Name 
  FROM Products 
 WHERE ProductID in (966, 967, 968)
```

Note: The list of ProdictID's is specified by search results.

This was working fine until I added a field to the `Product_Images` table for the Alt/Title text.

So, I tried the following

```
   SELECT ProductID, 
          Name,
          pi1.Filename, 
          pi1.alttag
     FROM Products 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * 
             FROM Product_Images 
            WHERE Product_Images.ProductID = Products.ProductID 
         ORDER BY Image_Type DESC, 
                  Image_Order 
            LIMIT 1) AS pi1 
               ON Products.ProductID = pi1.ProductID 
            WHERE Products.ProductID in (966, 967, 968)
```

But it's not working and I get the error message:

```
Unknown column 'products.productid' in 'where clause'
```

I've worked out that this error relates to the Products.ProductID in the JOIN derived table, and I've tried various ways to get the result, but now am just going round in circles.

Can anyone offer a suggestion please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't this work for you ?

Since you are trying to join the entire image table and return only 1 image and you also return only 1 product then you could directly use the `LEFT JOIN` on the `Product_Images` and move the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` outside of it as it will not affect the product only the images.

```
   SELECT p.ProductID, 
          p.Name,
          p.Price,
          i.Filename, 
          i.alttag
     FROM Products p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ProductID,
                  Filename,
                  alttag
             FROM Product_Images
         ORDER BY Image_Type DESC, 
                  Image_Order) AS i
       ON p.ProductID = i.ProductID
    WHERE p.ProductID IN (1, 2, 3)
 GROUP BY p.ProductID
 ORDER BY p.Price
```

**[Live DEMO.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/957bb/5/0)**

You can still apply the null to it as you had:

```
IFNULL(pi1.Filename, 'no_image.jpg') AS Image_Name, 
IFNULL(pi1.alttag, 'no information') AS Alt_Text
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but not really. I'm returning a list of 20+ products (I've edited the question to reflect this) so the limit needs to be on the image part. Also, I need to be able to extend the query to also return another image (different combination of Order By fields)...

Comment: @JezB so ProductID is not a primary field or are you dropping out the `WHERE Products.ProductID = 966`

Comment: ProductID is a primary key in Products, but not in Prodict_Images

Comment: @JezB if its a primary key on products and you are not dropping the `WHERE Products.ProductID = ID` then you will get only 1 product per query that is what I meant to say.

Comment: @JezB is the product order important to you or the products can come in random order?

Comment: Yes - the order needs to be able to be set/changed (e.g. Name, Price, etc).

Comment: Only problem was - when I copied to the live server, all the temp tables locked the database... I'm gonna have to try something else...